# Casting Object type in mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, casting

I have the folowing class and controller (mvc)

UI Model inherits DB model (ef4.0)

```
public class RegistrationModel : Model.User
    {
        [Required]
        public string PasswordText { get; set; }
    }
```

MVC controller

```
    public ActionResult Create(RegistrationModel registrationModel)
            {
                try
                {
                    Context ctx = new Context();
                    Model.User user = new Model.User();
                    user = (registrationModel as Model.User);
                    user.Password = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(registrationModel.PasswordText); //do encryption later on
...
                    ctx.Customer.Add(registrationModel as Model.User);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
    }
```

when i cast the registrationmodel to a user the type remains registrationmodel is there a way to cast it, without copying all its properties to a new user object?

```
                Model.User user = new Model.User();
                user.Active = registrationModel.Active;
                user.Blocked = registrationModel.Blocked;
//...
```

....

Answer (score 0):

How about using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).  Brilliant for automatically mapping data from models to view models and so on.

Answer (score 0):

correct. I had the same issue. it seems that all types of casting (document in MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) does not seem to work in MVC controllers.

for instance:

```
// IRREGULAR MVC CONTROLLERS BEHAVIOR 
// implicit casting
Model.User user = registrationModelInstance // won't case to base
// explicit casting
Model.User user = (Model.User)registrationModelInstance // won't case to base
```

i ended up using AutoMapper (similar to User-Defined conversion per MSDN). should look like that:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RegistrationModel, Model.User>();
Mapper.Map<RegistrationModel, Model.User>(registrationModelInstance);
```